# How can I post full form with AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How I can upload images and all element with one AJAX?
I would to upload images and send filename to database.... 
All element working fine, but I get nothing value in the images row.

here my AJAX CODE :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if($("#contentText").val()==="")
        {
            alert("Please enter some text!");
            return false;
        }

        var myData = $("#postA").serialize(); 

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "response.php", 
            data:myData,
            success:function(response){
            $(response).hide().prependTo("#responds").fadeIn("slow");
            document.getElementById("postA").reset(); 
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
```

and here my form code :

```
  <form id="postA">
    <textarea name="content_txt" id="contentText" ></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="id_userto" />
    <input type="text" name="thpost" />
    <input type="file" name="thpostimg" />
    <input type="text" name="thpostvid" />
    <input type="text" name="thpostmsc" />
    <input type="text" name="thpostlic" />
    <input type="hidden" name="content4txt" value="TRUE" />
    <button id="FormSubmit">Share</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Use this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/... it makes things pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: You can't.

You can't post files with ajax [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

But it can be faked. The accepted answer to this question may help [jQuery Ajax Submit form elements with multipart/form-data (Image/Video)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989726/jquery-ajax-submit-form-elements-with-multipart-form-data-image-video)